# Find and replace filename recursively in a directory

Tags: bash, find

I want to rename all the files in a folder which starts with `123_xxx.txt` to `xxx.txt`.

For example, my directory has:

```
123_xxx.txt
123_yyy.txt
123_zzz.txt
```

I want to rename all files as:

```
xxx.txt
yyy.txt
zzz.txt
```

I have seen some useful bash scripts in this forum but I'm still confused how to use it for my requirement.

Let us suppose I use:

```
for file in `find -name '123_*.txt'` ; do mv $file {?.txt} ; done
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
find . -name '123_*.txt' -type f -exec sh -c '
for f; do
    mv "$f" "${f%/*}/${f##*/123_}"
done' sh {} +
```

No pipes, no reads, no chance of breaking on malformed filenames, no non-standard tools or features.

Comment: This is making use of [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_0602) to strip the basename from the end of the path, then append a new name which has had the prefix up to 123_ removed. The two operators to read about  are `%` and `##`, the rest is simple globbing.

Answer (score 41):

```
find . -name "123*.txt" -exec rename 's/^123_//' {} ";"
```

will do it. No AWK, no for, no xargs needed, but **rename**, a very useful command from the Perl lib. It is not always included with Linux, but is easy to install from the repos.

Comment: This is superior to the overkill `awk` and looping answers above for those people who have the perl `rename`.

Comment: you miss a dot (.) before -name, doesn't run on mac

Comment: @ChanLe Gnu find on Linux doesn't require a directory name to act upon, but takes '.' automatically, if a name is missing.

Comment: `brew install rename` on Mac first

Comment: To add to this, the use of find is unnecessary if you're only talking about files in a single directory.  It's always best to keep it as simple as possible,  so you can just do `rename 's/^123_//' *` and it'll do the exact same thing.  Cheers.

Comment: @HodorTheCoder And if you've got `globstar` set in bash (`shopt -s globstar`), you can do it recursively: `rename 's/^123_//' **/*`

Comment: @HodorTheCoder: The title of the question asks for a solution for a directory recursively.

Comment: FYI, it is possible that one's computer has the util-linux rename command installed and not the Perl lib rename, the syntax is different between the two so check the help output. The util-linux rename can be made to work, but seems to only support find and rename of literal text strings. Also it will only rename the first occurrence of the match string in a file name, so you may need to run it multiple times.

Answer (score 20):

In case you want to replace string in file name called foo to bar you can use this in linux ubuntu, change file type for your needs

```
find -name "*foo*.filetype" -exec rename 's/foo/bar/' {} ";"
```

Comment: This is the most usable generalised answer

Comment: This really worked and is simple. How can I make this replace names of files in directories recursively.

Comment: @madu Find searches recursively into directories by default.  If you wanted it to only search the current directory, you would add a `-maxdepth 1` flag before the `-name …` flag.

Answer (score 8):

you could check 'rename' tool

for example

```
rename 's/^123_//' *.txt
```

or (gawk is needed)

```
find . -name '123_*.txt'|awk '{print "mv "$0" "gensub(/\/123_(.*\.txt)$/,"/\\1","g");}'|sh
```

**test**:

```
kent$  tree
.
|-- 123_a.txt
|-- 123_b.txt
|-- 123_c.txt
|-- 123_d.txt
|-- 123_e.txt
`-- u
    |-- 123_a.txt
    |-- 123_b.txt
    |-- 123_c.txt
    |-- 123_d.txt
    `-- 123_e.txt

1 directory, 10 files

kent$  find . -name '123_*.txt'|awk '{print "mv "$0" "gensub(/\/123_(.*\.txt)$/,"/\\1","g");}'|sh

kent$  tree
.
|-- a.txt
|-- b.txt
|-- c.txt
|-- d.txt
|-- e.txt
`-- u
    |-- a.txt
    |-- b.txt
    |-- c.txt
    |-- d.txt
    `-- e.txt

1 directory, 10 files
```

Comment: You should mention the homonym trap: you talk about special rename command that usurps the name of rename from util-linux (which does not deal with regular expressions).

Comment: The `rename` example isn't recursive. The `find` example is, but it needlessly doesn't use `rename` for renaming. And it pipes a generated script to `sh`, which is icky.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for me to modify the filename to all lower cases after the rename?
i mean.. any Xxx.txt should be xxx.txt finally?

Answer (score 6):

To expand on [Sorpigal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394625/2246380), if you want to replace the `123_` with `hello_`, you could use

```
    find . -name '123*.txt' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/\/123_/\/hello_}"' -- {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

A slight variation on Kent's that doesn't require gawk and is a little bit more readable, (although, thats debatable..)

`find . -name "123*" | awk '{a=$1; gsub(/123_/,""); printf "mv \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", a, $1}' | sh`

Comment: This was the only one that actually worked for me out the box on FreeNAS.

Comment: Worked like a charm on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using rename from util-linux 2.28.2 I had to use a different syntaxt:

```
find -name "*.txt" -exec rename -v "123_" ""  {} ";"
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided you don't have newlines in your filenames:

```
find -name '123_*.txt' | while IFS= read -r file; do mv "$file" "${file#123_}"; done
```

For a really safe way, provided your `find` supports the `-print0` flag (GNU `find` does):

```
find -name '123_*.txt' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do mv "$file" "${file#123_}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a little bash script for that.
Create a file named `recursive_replace_filename` with this content :

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $# -lt 2; then
  echo "usage: `basename $0` <to_replace> <replace_value>"
fi

for file in `find . -name "*$1*" -type f`; do
  mv "'$file'" "${file/'$1'/'$2'}"
done
```

Make executable an run:

```
$ chmod +x recursive_replace_filename
$ ./recursive_replace_filename 123_ ""
```

Keep note that this script can be dangerous, be sure you know what it's doing and in which folder you are executing it, and with which arguments. In this case, all files in the current folder, recursively, containing `123_` will be renamed.

Comment: Works as expected. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Tried the answer above but it didn't work for me cause i had the string inside folders and files name at the same time so here is what i did the following bash script:

```
  for fileType in d f
  do
    find  -type $fileType -iname "stringToSearch*" |while read file
    do
      mv $file $( sed -r "s/stringToSearch/stringToReplaceWith/" <<< $file )
    done
  done
```

First i began by replacing inside folders name then inside files name.

Comment: Worked well for me with spaces in the names of files. Just make sure you quote both vars in the mv line to work with spaces

Answer (score 1):

Here's the only solution to date that works:

```
find-rename-recursive --pattern '123_' --string '' -- . -type f -name "123_*"
```

All other solutions don't work for me--some even deleted files!

For details, see https://github.com/l3x/helpers#find-rename-recursive

Answer (score 0):

If the names are fixed you can visit each directory and perform the renaming in a subshell (to avoid changing the current directory) fairly simply. This is how I renamed a bunch of `new_paths.json` files each to `paths.json`:

```
for file in $(find root_directory -name new_paths.json)
  do
     (cd $(dirname $file) ; mv new_paths.json paths.json)
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

using the examples above, i used this to replace part of the file name... this was used to rename various data files in a directory, due to a vendor changing names.

`find . -name 'o3_cloudmed_*.*' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/cloudmed/revint}"' -- {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Below, the `find` command searches recursively in the tree from the directory passed as first parameter (here it is the current directory "."). The following parameters are predicates to filter the files we are looking for. The "-name" predicate is a pattern to which the current file name must match (here we want manage only filenames beginning with '123_' and terminating with '.txt'. The "-type" filters the type of the file ('f' means regular file, 'd' would mean directory...). The "-exec" predicate runs a command line into which '{}' is the current file name and the ';' terminates the command.

```
find . -name '123_*.txt' -type f -exec bash -c 'name={};mv $name ${name//123_//}' \;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you also explain your solution too?

Answer (score -2):

```
prename s/^123_// 123_*
```

See [prename in the official Perl5 wiki](https://socialtext.net/perl5/prename). Copy for your convenience:

`prename` - A script that renames files according to a regular expression. (Where was the original published?) Originally named rename, it is found mostly as prename because the original one clashes with the rename command from the `util-linux` package. Numerous forks and reimplementations:

- http://search.cpan.org/dist/rename/
- http://search.cpan.org/dist/pbr/
- http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Rename/
- http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-PerlMove/
- http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-FileTools-BulkRename/
- http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlmv/
- http://training.perl.com/scripts/rename
- https://github.com/msabramo/ren-regexp

Comment: premane is not recognized in my bash shell as well as command prompt. FYI, m having perl installed...

Comment: It helps to spell the command correctly. Read the document I linked to where to get it.

Comment: I have `prename`, but it ain't recursive.