# Find and replace filename recursively in a directory with various names

Tags: macos, bash

I have the following file structure

```
./lib/mylib-client.c
./lib/mylib-object.h
./lib/mylib-rpc-wrapper.c
./lib/mylib-session-base.c
./lib/mylib-session-base.lo
./lib/mylib-session-base.o
./lib/mylibobj.c
./lib/mylibobj.lo
./lib/mylibobj.o
./lib/mylibobj.vala
./lib/mylibrpc-transport.c
./net/cluster/.deps/mylib-config.Po
./net/cluster/.deps/mylib-db.Po
./net/common/mylib-config.c
./net/common/mylib-config.h
./net/common/mylib-db.c
./net/common/mylib-db.h
./net/daemon/.deps/mylib-config.Po
./net/daemon/.deps/mylib-daemon.Po
./net/daemon/.deps/mylib-test.Po
./net/daemon/mylib
./net/daemon/mylib-config.o
./net/daemon/mylib-daemon.c
./net/daemon/mylib-daemon.o
```

That I want to recursively rename to :

```
./lib/libvertio-client.c
./lib/libvertio-object.h
./lib/libvertio-rpc-wrapper.c
./lib/libvertio-session-base.c
./lib/libvertio-session-base.lo
./lib/libvertio-session-base.o
./lib/libvertioobj.c
./lib/libvertioobj.lo
./lib/libvertioobj.o
./lib/libvertioobj.vala
./lib/libvertiorpc-transport.c
./net/cluster/.deps/libvertio-config.Po
./net/cluster/.deps/libvertio-db.Po
./net/common/libvertio-config.c
./net/common/libvertio-config.h
./net/common/libvertio-db.c
./net/common/libvertio-db.h
./net/daemon/.deps/libvertio-config.Po
./net/daemon/.deps/libvertio-daemon.Po
./net/daemon/.deps/libvertio-test.Po
./net/daemon/libvertio
./net/daemon/libvertio-config.o
./net/daemon/libvertio-daemon.c
./net/daemon/libvertio-daemon.o
```

I have found this : [Find and replace filename recursively in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393607/find-and-replace-filename-recursively-in-a-directory)

But i can't figure out what to change

```
find . -name "mylib*" | awk '{a=$1; gsub(/mylib/,"libvertio"); printf "mv \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", a, $1}' | sh
```

Doesn't work. What Am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `rename` script:

```
find . -name "mylib*" -exec rename 's/mylib/libvertio/' '{}' \;
```

**Without `rename`:**

```
find . -name "mylib*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/\/mylib//libvertio}"' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: I only use OSX and I have rename (installed it using `home brew`)