# rename files of a folder and its folders children

Tags: regex, linux, perl, shell

I would like to add prefix on all files in a folder and in all files in all of folder children.

Exemple :

```
 hello\file1
 hello2\file2
 file3
 file4
```

the result should be after adding the prefix PRE_

```
 hello\PRE_file1
 hello2\PRE_file2
 PRE_file3
 PRE_file4
```

i tried to do this :

`find . -type f -exec rename 's/^/PRE_/' '{}' \;`

but it modify all the name.
Thank you

Comment: The unix `rename` command is probably what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace filename recursively in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393607/find-and-replace-filename-recursively-in-a-directory)

Comment: find . -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(dirname "$0")/PRE_$(basename "$0")"' {} \;

Comment: thank you william Pursell. That was really helpfull !

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use only perl if you want, without any additional modules:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($prefix, $dir) = ('PRE_', '/home');
sub loop_dirs {
    my $path = $_[0];
    if (-d $path) { # if directory
         opendir my $dh, $path or die "$!";
         loop_dirs($path.'/'.$_) for grep ! /^\.{1,2}$/, readdir $dh; close $dh;
    } elsif (-e $path) { # if file
         prefix_add($path, $prefix); # do smth with file, e.g. rename
    }
}
sub prefix_add { my ($path, $pref) = @_; $path =~ s/([^\/]+)$/$pref$1/; rename $_[0], $path }
loop_dirs($dir);
```

This code works well both on Windows(ActivePerl) and Linux