# How to loop through files in all sub directories?

Tags: perl, file, loops, recursion

In `perl` I can loop through the files in the current directory by doing the following:

```
foreach $file (<*.*>) {
        print "$file found\n";
        # do stuff
}
```

How can I do the same thing but to all files in all sub-directories?

Comment: If you don't want to use additional modules, may be my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407997/rename-files-of-a-folder-and-its-folders-children/36425685#36425685) will help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule) is a great module for recursively listing files.

All files (as you asked):

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

for my $qfn (File::Find::Rule->in(".")) {
   ...
}
```

Just the files with "." in their name (as per your example):

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

for my $qfn (File::Find::Rule->name("*.*")->in(".")) {
   ...
}
```

Adding `->file` limits the results to plain files (filtering out directories).

Answer (score 0):

I find [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) unnecessarily fussy and clumsy, especially for a simple application like this. Ultimately it is just a wrapper for the core module [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find), and I think the base class itself is a good choice for a straightforward application like yours

`File::Find` allows you to specify a *callback* subroutine that will be executed for every node (file or directory) within a specified root directory

By default, that subroutine is called with the following context

- `$File::Find::name` is set to the full path to the node
- `$File::Find::dir` is set to the path to the directory containing the
- `$_` is set to the name of the node, without its path
- The *current working directory* is set to `$File::Find::dir`

If you want, say, to list all files beneath your current directory, then you would write this. All nodes but plain files are rejected using the `-f` file test operator, works on `$_` and finds the right file because the working directory has been temporarily changed

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Find 'find';

find(\&wanted, '.');

sub wanted {

    return unless -f;

    print $File::Find::name, "\n";
}
```

If you prefer, you can use an anonymous subroutine within the call to `find`. This code does exactly the same thing

```
find(sub {
    return unless -f;
    print $File::Find::name, "\n";
}, '.');
```

Comment: I prefer the use of `File::Find::Rule`.  You haven't properly explained your objection to it.