# Bash: recursively rename part of a file

Tags: bash

I have files in many directories that have the date Feb28 in them. I'd like to change them all to Mar2. For example, in one directory, I have

```
file1_Feb28_01.json
anothername_Feb28_02.txt
```

I want these to instead be

```
file1_Mar2_01.json
anothername_Mar2_02.txt
```

I have other similar files in other directories.

So far I have tried:

```
find . -name '*Feb28*' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "{1/Feb28/Mar2}"' -- {} \;
```

And in a separate bash script, I have tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1" | sed 's/*Feb28*$/*Mar1*/'
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393607/find-and-replace-filename-recursively-in-a-directory), but it doesn't seem to directly answer my question.

Comment: I think your `find` command should *almost* work; replace `-- {}` by `- {}` and `"{1/Feb28/Mar2}"` by `"${1/Feb28/Mar2}"`?

Comment: It works! Thanks @BenjaminW.

Comment: The *questions* are not exact duplicates, but the answers in the dupe target cover this exact case as well.