# Rename Multiple files in Multiple directories

Tags: linux, file, for-loop, cp, mv

I would like to rename a Multiple files in Multiple directories into a single filename.
Let say i have files

- k1-abc in one directory
- k1-def in 2nd directory
- k1-adt in 3rd directory

The common thing in all the file names is k1 followed by some other name

I need to rename all the filenames as Dockerfile
I dont have rename command in my Linux

what is the best command to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace filename recursively in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393607/find-and-replace-filename-recursively-in-a-directory)

Comment: Thanks for the reply find . -name ''k1-*" -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/\/k1-*_/Dockerfile/}"' -- {} \;     It works only for one directory am i doing something wrong. it doesnt affect for all the directories

Answer (score 0):

This will rename all files only in `/path/to/files` that begin with `k1` and renames them to `Dockerfile`.

```
find /path/to/files -type f -name "k1*" -exec mv -v {} Dockerfile \;
```