# Command line to bulk change charset from file names recursively (UTF-8-Latin1)

Tags: utf-8, filenames, iso-8859-1, iconv

1. Changing from Linux Mint Cinammon to Mint KDE causes something
   with the filenames char sets of all partitions! Now the names are
   messed. I've already tried to change locales, unsuccessfully
2. The problem concerns accented characters (I'm a brazilian
   portuguese speaker)
3. The big problem is that I have to deal with approximately 60GB+ of
   60.000+ files (PDFs mainly), in 1000+ folders and subfolders in a fat32 partition
4. So I found over internet this command line that works fine for me,
   but it lacks the recursive feature, i.e., it does not apply the
   changes to the subfolders, and the files contained in subfolders. It
   just apply the desired changes (that is: rename the file from one
   char set to another) to the actual plain single folder

My question is: How to turn this command line recursive? Is it even possible?

```
ls -1 | while read arquivo ; do novo="`echo $arquivo \
| iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1`"; if [ "$novo" != "$arquivo" ] ;\
then mv "$arquivo" "$novo"; fi done
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393607/find-and-replace-filename-recursively-in-a-directory

Comment: Sorry but it's not the same case, or I can't figure how it can be applied to this case

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'novo="`echo $1 \                                
| iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1`"; if [ "$novo" != "$1" ] ;\
then mv "$1" "$novo"; fi' -- {} \
```

You may change `.` to any directory appropriate and filter files by name with `-name`, see `man find`.

To only affect files ending in `.pdf` you could use

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec bash -c 'novo="`echo $1 \                                
| iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1`"; if [ "$novo" != "$1" ] ;\
then mv "$1" "$novo"; fi' -- {} \
```

One-liner for copy&paste:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'novo="`echo $1 | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-    1`"; f [ "$novo" != "$1" ] ; then mv "$1" "$novo"; fi' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Tried this out, yeah! 1) it's recursive, 2) do the trick. But... my output was this one for all files (br-portuguese). I'm missing something?

"mv: não foi possível mover './.local/share/Trash/files/2017.2/Ã©tica livros novos/SINGER, P. Ã'$'\302\211''tica prÃ¡tica.pdf' para './.local/share/Trash/files/2017.2/ética livros novos/SINGER, P. Ética prática.pdf': Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado"
Typed this way:
"find . -type f -exec bash -c 'novo="`echo $1 | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1`"; if [ "$novo" != "$1" ] ; then mv "$1" "$novo"; fi' -- {} \;"

Comment: Sorry rkta, by now I'm still testing the command line. Just tried to specify folder and extension, with little success. My feelings tell this is the way to go, thanks,  I'll leave a comment soon showing my concrete results and asking for further help or improvement!!

Comment: I have just founded out this command, my problem is solved: `convmv -r --notest -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8 *` . Thanks!