# How to recursively remove file extension from file?

Tags: bash, shell, find, file-extension

So I just ran the following command to add a file extension to a bunch of files.  I thought I would undo them one by one, but it turns out I need to undo them all at one time, how do I reverse this?

```
find . -name '*.targetFileType' -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.not \;
```

- Before the file was:  **aFile.targetFileType**
- Now it is: **aFile.targetFileType.not**

I need to return it to aFile.targetFileType

Comment: Similar question: [Find and replace filename recursively in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393607/find-and-replace-filename-recursively-in-a-directory#9394625)

Comment: `find . -name '*.not' -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "$1" "${1/.not/}"' -- {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to reverse with:

`for f in $(find . -name '*.not' -type f); do mv ${f} $(echo ${f} | sed 's/.not//g'); done;`

Comment: note there is no need to launch extra processes to convert `file.not` to  just `file`. try `echo mv "${f}" "${f%.not}"` and remove `echo` when you are sure it is working correctly. Good luck.

Comment: When a filename starts with `-`, this will be seen as an option. Use `mv -- "${f}" "${f%.not}"`.